# Setting up Tap Gesture on UIView on an NSObject, even if delegate is set on View Controller doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

in VideoPlayer.h:

```
@interface VideoPlayer : NSObject <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *playerView;
```

in VideoPlayer.m custom init method:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidTapScreen:)];
tgr.delegate = self; // tried with and without
tgr.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; // tried with and without
[self.playerView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
```

....

```
- (void)userDidTapScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
  NSLog(@"user tapped");
}
```

Because this object is part of an SDK, we don't have a view controller. But even if I set the delegate in the View Controller of a project using the SDK, I still have no luck. If I had another view as a subView to self.playerView, the tap gesture works on that view, even if I'm still adding gesture to self.playerView. I have removed all subviews to make sure nothing is blocking and when I do that, still no luck. I know that typically view controllers handle this and if I put all the tap gesture code in the view controllers, it works, but if I only set the view controller as the delegate and that's the only gesture code on the view controller, it doesn't work.

When added to a project's view controller:

```
VideoPlayer *player = [[VideoPlayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 320, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:player.playerView];

UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[player.playerView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

This isn't ideal for our SDK. I think we could tell anyone using it to set delegate in their view controller, but that doesn't even work when that's the only line in the view controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've done a lot of tap gestures both in code and through IB and never this problem.

Comment: Gesture recognizers have to be attached to UIViews (or descendants).  NSObjects don't receive touch events for the recognizers to observe.

Comment: @Avi, the gesture recognizer is attached to a UIView called playerView as shown in my code in the original question.

Comment: You're 100%, of course.  I must have misread the code.  Have you verified that playerView is non-nil at the point where you add the GR?